Nsight Compute + Roofline chart
I am new to using Nsight Compute and have a question about the roofline chart. When I profile different kernels on Nsight Compute and view their roofline charts, nothing is shown for some kernels, such as the histogram (in CUDA samples), which doesn’t have floating point operations. Does the roofline chart work only for kernels with floating point operations? I have seen in some academic papers that they classify different types of kernels using the roofline model. How do they do that?
